# Python: Infinite loop with "with open"

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I have a huge file around 5 GB (with around 7.2 million trees) with particle ID (first column) and time (second column) as follows, which tells us how the IDs of the particles evolves

```
#Tree 0, Nbranches=2
1544212658   -1.0000
#Tree 1, Nbranches=2
2147749983   -1.0000
#Tree 2, Nbranches=7
1644822649   -1.0000
1611272315   17.6766
1594523770   10.2310
1661603959   10.0127
1661624438   10.7100
#Tree 3, Nbranches=8
252530795   -1.0000
319647854   10.7497
...
```

and I have a list of Ids as a form of list whose evolution I want to track following the above file. I wrote a code which works for a small dataset that I made, but everytime I run it with the actual dataset (on my university cluster), the code keeps on looping. I included a print statement to track the progress of the code and I can notice that when it hits around 7.2 millionth tree, it starts allover again from `Tree 0`. The thing that baffles me is that I simply don't understand why the code loops, Can anyone see any logical falacies in the code? Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

The code:

```
import numpy as np
pid=[]
pid_pass=[]   
ids=np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\Nin\\Downloads\\gg\\100kpc_cumulative_halo_ids.txt') #list of initial 
halos as a list                                                           
id_final=[]
with open('C:\\Users\\Nin\\Downloads\\Sel_merg_hist.txt','r') as inf:
      for line in inf:
         if line.startswith("#"):
             print line 
             del pid[:]

         else :
            parts = line.split() # split line into parts
            pid.append((int(parts[0]),float(parts[1])))
            for i in range(len(ids)):
                 if ids[i]==int(parts[0]) and float(parts[1]) == -1 :
                    id_final.append(int(parts[0]))
                    pid_pass.append(ids[i])

                 elif ids[i]==int(parts[0]) :
                    id_final.append(pid[0][0])
                    pid_pass.append(ids[i])



id_left=list(set(ids).difference(set(pid_pass)))  #list of ids not used,                                                                                                                                           which didn't merge until after z=10      

id_left= map(int,id_left) #convert float to int to get rid of .0

id_final=id_final+id_left                                        


file = open("100kpc_final_ids.txt", "w")
for index in range(len(id_final)):
        file.write(str(id_final[index]) +  "\n")
file.close()
```

Thanks to @szym, it seems the main loop which reads every line of the file doesn't quit, it keeps on looping. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: Include the print statement you mentioned in the code.

Comment: What happens if you reduce the loop to just `for line in inf: if line.startswith("#"): print line`?

Comment: Ok, that was a great advice. Thanks. It doesn't stop at the end of the file, it keeps looping. It restarted when it hit the end of the file. Any idea why? I thought the "with" command automatically closes the file at the end.

Comment: This seems like a bug. The `with` statement does not matter here. The `for line in inf` loop should terminate at the end of the file.

Comment: Any idea where the bug is?

Comment: Things to try: commenting out parts of the inner loop until it terminates; use a smaller file (you can bisect it) until you figure out which content causes the bug.